# Retrieving results recursively from mySQL database based on date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple database like so:

```
id int
name varchar(20)
date date // stored as "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"
```

I have a front end where whenever I input data, it will always insert the date the data was inserted.

I want to return the data like so using PHP and mySQL:

```
DATE

id - name // however many of these fall under the same day in the database, are printed
id - name
id - name

DATE

id - name // however many of these fall under the same day in the database, are printed
id - name
etc
```

I'm not really sure how to make a loop to do this. I am able to extract the following data like so:

```
    <table class="table">
        <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, date FROM database");
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        { ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><?php echo $result['date']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result['id']; echo $result['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>  
        <?php 
        } ?>
    </table>
```

This prints (for example):

```
2008-11-23 08:32:32
id - name
2008-11-23 11:12:06
id - name
2008-11-23 05:42:12
id - name
2008-11-23 07:45:23
id - name
```

when I want

```
November 23rd, 2008
id - name
id - name
```

I know I need two loops, one loop to print the date, and then another to print all data under that date, and then change a value so that the day previous is printed, and so on, but I'm not sure how to incrementally decrease a date.

Comment: in the same table, you insert many id-names with the same date,in the sime moment, true?

Comment: With a little sql union magic, you could do it in one query, and one loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **GROUP BY** clause

```
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

and in the for loop add the date as a heading if the present date is not equal to the date already printed. (You have to have a variable to store the date that was printed)

```
<table class="table">
        <?php
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, date FROM database GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d') order by date ASC");
        $PrevDate = false;
        while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
        {
           if($PrevDate!=$result['date']){
 ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6"><?php echo $result['date']; ?></td>
            </tr>
       <? } ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $result['id']; echo $result['name']; ?></td>
            </tr>  
        <?php 
         $PrevDate = $result['date'];
        } ?>
    </table>
```

This should do it.